# Does the order in which engines in commercial airliners are turned on matter?

Tags: aircraft-systems, engine, pushback

I've seen videos on youtube where the pilots always turn on engines 4 and 3 (in a B747-4) first and then turn 2 and 1 on after pushback. Is there a reason behind this, and does the same reason apply to all multi-engine aircraft?

Comment: There's a lively debate about this, https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/415625-747-2-engine-start.html.  The consensus seems to be that starting one at a time is nicer to the APU, and starting some before pushback ends saves you precious seconds at a busy airport.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Does [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8109/62) help? [This one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/71059/62) and [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47377/62) might also be relevant.

Comment: Short answer is it depends on the airplane.